# An error when assigning input bindings when creating components dynamically

Tags: angular

I have a simple component:

```ts
@Component({
  template: 'I am {{color}} component'
})
export class ColorComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() color: string;
```

I'm adding this component like this:

```ts
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('container', {read: ViewContainerRef}) container: ViewContainerRef;

  componentRef: ComponentRef<ColorComponent>;

  constructor(private vc: ViewContainerRef, private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.createComponent();
  }

  createComponent() {
    this.container.clear();
    const factory: ComponentFactory<any> = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ColorComponent);
    this.componentRef: ComponentRef<ColorComponent> = this.container.createComponent(factory);
    this.componentRef.instance.color = 'green';
  }
}
```

And although the template is rendered correctly:

```ts
I am green component
```

I get the following error in console:

> Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value:
>   'CD_INIT_VALUE'. Current value: 'I am green component'. It seems like
>   the view has been created after its parent and its children have been
>   dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook ?

Why the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```ts
export class ColorComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}
  private _color: string;
  @Input() set color(val: string) {
    this._color = val;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

if you don't control the dynamically added component you can also

```ts
componentRef.instance.color = 'green';
componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```

Comment: thanks, it's working fine now. Can you provide details on what caused the problem? Or maybe some resources to read about the matter?

Comment: The error is thrown when a bound property value changes during change detection. I guess the cause is where you call the code from that adds the component, but your question doesn't contain information about that. With an explicit sync change detection run, Angular gets the value copies it holds for change detection updated and doesn't recognize a change anymore.

Comment: thanks, I'll read about that. `componentRef.instance.color = 'green';` - I'm changing value here

Comment: I know, but I don't know where this code is in your application, and wehere it is being called from.

Comment: I've updated the details in the question. Please take a look

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is `ngAfterViewInit()` If you call `createComponent()` from a `(click)="createComponent()"` it will work fine, because here Angular **expects changes**, but `ngAfterViewInit()` is called by change detection, and it doesn't like when change detection itself causes changes.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for your feedback. I'll try and let you know